# Nothing happens with a `git pull`

Tags: git, shell, git-pull

Since yesterday, I have a big issue with my Professional computer : I cannot use `git pull`. This is really weird because every other git command's works.

What I tried :

- Reinstalling Github for Windows, Git Shell, etc...
- Look if I can access to the remote server (git push work, I can ping the remote server).

`GIT_TRACE=1 git pull` return :

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull
trace: exec: 'git-pull'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull'
```

An other thing is strange : now on a git repository, I didn't see the current repository on the git shell :

```
MY_USER@MY_COMPUTER /c/Github/myRepo 
$
```

Usually, my CLI looks like this :

```
MY_USER@MY_COMPUTER /c/Github/myRepo <develop>
$
```

I'm thinking the problem is software because I got an 'entreprise' package update just before the issue.
**My configuration** : Windows 8.1 Professional with Github for Windows and I'm using Git shell.

If someone has an idea to fix this or how can I debug this command, I appreciate.

**EDIT**

`git remote -v` returns :

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://MY_USER@git-SI.enterprise.fr/PROJECT/windows/PROJECT_repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://MY_USER@git-SI.enterprise.fr/PROJECT/windows/PROJECT_repo.git (push)
```

`git status`returns :

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: What does `git remote -v` and `git status` return in `/c/Github/myRepo`?

Comment: @VonC I answer you in the Post.

Comment: Are you using the latest Git for windows 1.9.4? does `git fetch` work?

Comment: Yes, and `git fetch` works

Comment: If "`your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit`", there would be nothing to pull, only to push. Did you try pushing?

Comment: It's rejected :  `! [rejected]        develop -> develop (fetch first)`.

Comment: Is the `git status` still at `ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit` after you fetched?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65566/discussion-between-joffrey-kern-and-vonc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was an update of our enterprise antivirus software : it blocks all bash commands (like `ls`, `clear` on my prompt command).

Comment: No problem. I didn't think about the antivirus in our chat session.

Comment: Next time, you'll think it.