# git pull not working even no errors occurred

Tags: git, github

I'm trouble with using git pull command.

I called 'git pull', but nothing happened, and even no errors occurred!
It worked well before and not working today. What should I do?

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull

16:07:11.030735 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git pull

16:07:11.031160 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok

16:07:11.032437 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok

16:07:11.032805 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/my/repository.git

[yjpark@uws64-211 www]$
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you set your origin repository to `https://github.com/my/repository.git` then the problem is that this does not exist. That do you get if you run `git remote show origin` ?

Comment: @batzilis I have manually changed the address to write questions. Of course, the settings are correct, and 'git pull' worked fine a few days ago.

Comment: Is your command just not doing anything because there are no changes to pull?

Comment: @entpnerd No. I already pushed one commit from another computer. if that case, git might say "already up-to-date", but nothing is shown.

Comment: Stupid question: Have you tried restarting your machine?

Comment: @entpnerd Well.. I'm using web hosting service, I can not turn off the machine at will. I need to ask if they can restart the server. Thanks.

Comment: @YoungjinPark if that doesn't work, try checking out this other question on this topic. Note that I'm hesitant to declare this question a duplicate because your issue could have a completely different cause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121222/nothing-happens-with-a-git-pull

Comment: @YoungjinPark did you end up getting the pull command to work after?

Comment: @entpnerd I solved the problem. It was a git version problem on the server. Thanks!

Comment: @YoungjinPark Consider adding an answer to the question so that it can be useful for others who encounter your problem. I'd be happy to upvote it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a git version problem on the server.

Server administrator downgraded git's version, and it works fine now. :)